# Vscode no intellisense/autocompletion with multiple projects

Tags: c#, vue.js, visual-studio-code, .net-core, vuetify.js

I have a multi projects in vscode, the whole backend in C# net core and a Website with VueJs and Vuetify. When I load the entire project in the web I can't see the intellisense/autocompletion as show the picture, just get a /v-layout.
But when I just open only the web without the backend I get all intellisense/autocompletion as expected.
Any idea why is this happened?
Thanks,

Sorry my english.

[image: Doesn't work]
[image: It works!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the issue with `vetur` plugin with a multi-root project or sub-folder support, states in their [milestone 1.0](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/873): 
"Currently, Vetur provides no multi-root support. Also, if your Vue project is not on the top-level, Vetur will not activate..."